# Changing file paths in included makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have project and few subproject

Some of subprojects are very independent. They works without any knowledge about whole project, they are build differently and have its own `Makefile`. This `Makefile` is located in subproject root dir.
Whole subproject is built to single object file.

Is there any way to properly include such object file to main `Makefile`? By "properly" I mean preserving all dependencies and building this file using method in subproject `Makefile`.

I tried to create rule for building this object file:

```
path_to_subproject/some_object.o:
    $(MAKE) -C path_to_subproject
```

But that way I cannot preserve any dependencies.

What I need is to convert all relative path in subproject `Makefile` and include it to main `Makefile`.

Another way could be telling main `Makefile` that `some_object.o` is built using different `Makefile`, so `make` should use it to check dependencies etc.

Comment: Can you modify the subproject makefiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the makefile in `subproject/` looks like this:

```
some_object.o: some_source.cc some_header.h
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ -I.
```

You can modify it like so:

```
HERE:=/full/path/to/subproject

$(HERE)/some_object.o: $(HERE)/some_source.cc $(HERE)/some_header.h
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ -I$(HERE)
```

This will act the same as the original when used by itself (except that you can no longer `make some_object.o` from `subproject/`, you must `make /full/path/to/subproject/some_object.o`-- that can be fixed, but you must make a design decision or two).

Now you can add a line to the bottom of the master makefile:

```
include path_to_subproject/Makefile
```

and then the master makefile can use that object:

```
some_executable: local_object.o /full/path/to/subproject/some_object.o
    whatever
```

More sophisticated variations are possible, once you have this working.